# MYSQL Groupby and Orderby Query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I want to group by the data with the highest possible contract_id with respect to a particular player_id.
It sounds simple enough but it is not working as expected.

```
SELECT distinct(f1.player_id), f1.contract_id,f1.feature_id
from (select p.player_id,p.player_name, p.player_no, CASE c.action
when 'submit' then 'تقديم'
when 'approve' then 'موافقة'
when 'reject'  then 'رفض'
when 'object'  then 'اعتراض'
when 'resubmit' then 'اعادة تقديم'
END as action, c.new_time, Case co.status
when 'free' then 'حر'
when 'active' then 'نشط'
when 'expired'  then 'منتهي'
when 'loan'  then 'معار'
when 'loan expire' then 'ااعارة منتهية'
END as status, co.contract_id,c.feature_id
FROM contract co
INNER JOIN player_profile p ON p.player_id = co.player_id
INNER JOIN new_request c ON c.contract_id = co.contract_id
INNER JOIN club cl ON co.club_id = cl.club_id
where co.reqeust_type='new' 
) as f1
order by f1.player_id asc;
```

Data Set:
**Full Data Set**

[image: Full Data Set]

```
SELECT distinct(f1.player_id), f1.contract_id,f1.feature_id
from (select p.player_id,p.player_name, p.player_no, CASE c.action
when 'submit' then 'تقديم'
when 'approve' then 'موافقة'
when 'reject'  then 'رفض'
when 'object'  then 'اعتراض'
when 'resubmit' then 'اعادة تقديم'
END as action, c.new_time, Case co.status
when 'free' then 'حر'
when 'active' then 'نشط'
when 'expired'  then 'منتهي'
when 'loan'  then 'معار'
when 'loan expire' then 'ااعارة منتهية'
END as status, co.contract_id,c.feature_id
FROM contract co
INNER JOIN player_profile p ON p.player_id = co.player_id
INNER JOIN new_request c ON c.contract_id = co.contract_id
INNER JOIN club cl ON co.club_id = cl.club_id
where co.reqeust_type='new' 
) as f1
group by f1.player_id 
order by f1.player_id asc;
```

**data set for query**
[image: data set for query 2]

I want to get Player_ID 7 and contract ID 301.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that it does not work as expected? Pls provide expected outcome and the outcome returned by the 2 queries!

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your "base" subquery :

```
SELECT p.player_id,p.player_name, p.player_no, 
CASE c.action
  when 'submit' then 'تقديم'
  when 'approve' then 'موافقة'
  when 'reject'  then 'رفض'
  when 'object'  then 'اعتراض'
  when 'resubmit' then 'اعادة تقديم'
END as action, 
c.new_time, 
CASE co.status
  when 'free' then 'حر'
  when 'active' then 'نشط'
  when 'expired'  then 'منتهي'
  when 'loan'  then 'معار'
  when 'loan expire' then 'ااعارة منتهية'
END as status, 
co.contract_id,
c.feature_id
FROM contract co
  INNER JOIN player_profile p ON p.player_id = co.player_id
  INNER JOIN new_request c ON c.contract_id = co.contract_id
  INNER JOIN club cl ON co.club_id = cl.club_id
WHERE co.reqeust_type='new'
```

If you want to get the highest `contract_id` per player, you should do a `MAX(contract_id)` and `GROUP BY` player , like this

```
SELECT MAX(co.contract_id), 
  p.player_id,p.player_name, p.player_no, 
CASE c.action
  when 'submit' then 'تقديم'
  when 'approve' then 'موافقة'
  when 'reject'  then 'رفض'
  when 'object'  then 'اعتراض'
  when 'resubmit' then 'اعادة تقديم'
END as action, 
c.new_time, 
CASE co.status
  when 'free' then 'حر'
  when 'active' then 'نشط'
  when 'expired'  then 'منتهي'
  when 'loan'  then 'معار'
  when 'loan expire' then 'ااعارة منتهية'
END as status, 
co.contract_id,
c.feature_id
FROM contract co
  INNER JOIN player_profile p ON p.player_id = co.player_id
  INNER JOIN new_request c ON c.contract_id = co.contract_id
  INNER JOIN club cl ON co.club_id = cl.club_id
WHERE co.reqeust_type='new' 
GROUP BY co.player_id
```

Then, you can retrieve only the player your want from this query, like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT MAX(co.contract_id) AS contractid, 
  p.player_id,p.player_name, p.player_no, 
CASE c.action
  when 'submit' then 'تقديم'
  when 'approve' then 'موافقة'
  when 'reject'  then 'رفض'
  when 'object'  then 'اعتراض'
  when 'resubmit' then 'اعادة تقديم'
END as action, 
c.new_time, 
CASE co.status
  when 'free' then 'حر'
  when 'active' then 'نشط'
  when 'expired'  then 'منتهي'
  when 'loan'  then 'معار'
  when 'loan expire' then 'ااعارة منتهية'
END as status, 
co.contract_id,
c.feature_id
FROM contract co
  INNER JOIN player_profile p ON p.player_id = co.player_id
  INNER JOIN new_request c ON c.contract_id = co.contract_id
  INNER JOIN club cl ON co.club_id = cl.club_id
WHERE co.reqeust_type='new' 
GROUP BY co.player_id
) T
WHERE player_id = 7
```

Comment: @SyedAbdullahAli glad to read. But if it answers the question, mark it as accepted please ;)